# Radio button does not hide/show section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Description:**

I have 3 sections in my page that I want to do, each having a radio button to select an object.

**Problem:**

I am trying to figure out a problem where when I press the "online radio button" it will show up the section that I need. But when I press the "Face to Face" the online section keeps appearing.

**Expected Result:**

Each Radio button should work with each section and hide the other one.

**HTML CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Online").hide();
  $("#Face").hide();
  $("#Payment").hide();
});

$(document).on("change", "#choice1", function() {
  var radioValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(radioValue);
  if (($(this).value = "Online")) showOnline();
  else if  (($(this).value = "Face To Face")) showFace();
});

function showOnline() {
  $("#Online").show();
  $("#Face").hide();
}
function showFace() {
  $("#Face").show();
  $("#Online").hide();
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
}

.covid {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.covid h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.covid img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
.covid p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.textred {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
.textgreen {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: green;
}
.status {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.status h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.china {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
.amazon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
.reviews {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.reviews h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bolded {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
.stars {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 20px;
  magrin: 15%;
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre;
  color: yellow;
}
.review {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 20%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.mainscreen {
  background-color: white;
  height: 1800px;
}
.avatar {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.choice1{
  margin-left: 45%;
}
.choice3{
  margin-left: 43%;
}
.choice4{
  margin-left: 41%;
}
.button1{
  margin-left: 48%;
}
.notreviews{
  margin-top: -9%;
}
<div class="w3-panel w3-white w3-card-4 reviews">
<h2>How will you like your appointment to be?</h2>
<section id="choice1">
    <form>
        <input
            type="radio"
            name="choice"
            class="choice1"
            id="OL"
            value="Online"
            />
        Online
        <input
            type="radio"
            name="choice"
            class="choice2"
            id="FTF"
            value="Face To Face"
            />
        Face To Face
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="submitAnswer()" class="button1">
    Submit Answer
    </button>
</section>
</div>
<!-- Online Section -->
<div class="w3-panel w3-white w3-card-4 reviews" id="Online">
<h2>Online Appointments</h2>
<section id="choice2">
    <form>
        <input
            type="radio"
            name="choice2"
            class="choice3"
            id="ZOOM"
            value="Zoom"
            />
        Zoom
        <input
            type="radio"
            name="choice2"
            class="choice2"
            id="MEET"
            value="Meet"
            />
        Google Meet
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="submitOnlineAnswer()" class="button1">
    Submit Answer
    </button>
</section>
</div>
<!-- FTF Section -->
<div class="w3-panel w3-white w3-card-4 reviews" id="Face">
<h2>Face To Face Appointments</h2>
<section id="choice3">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="choice3" class="choice4" id="Amazon" value="Ama"/> Amazon Rainforst Location
        <input type="radio" name="choice3" class="choice2" id="China" value="China" /> China Location
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="submitFTFAnswer()" class="button1" >Submit Answer</button>
</section>
</div>
<section id="section">
```

**Jquery Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Online").hide();
  $("#Face").hide();
  $("#Payment").hide();
});

$(document).on("change", "#choice1", function() {
  var radioValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(radioValue);
  if (($(this).value = "Online")) showOnline();
  else if  (($(this).value = "Face To Face")) showFace();
});

function showOnline() {
  $("#Online").show();
  $("#Face").hide();
}
function showFace() {
  $("#Face").show();
  $("#Online").hide();
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: What does your `console.log(radioValue);` show you?

Comment: When I looked on the console its a blank  space with `appointments.js:9` no null or anything

Comment: Exactly. You set `radioValue` to `$(this).val()` but here, `this` refers to `#choice1` which is a `<section>` which has no value. Instead, you want to bind the change event to the radio buttons, which do have values

Comment: OP thx can you do it as an answer so I can give you credit @j08691